# Creating more than one framebuffer

Tags: opengl, go, framebuffer

I've been able to create a single framebuffer and render it to a texture. However when I try to create another one I start getting very strange results.

I've learned that generating a framebuffer first and then it's textures should give me the correct results. However in my case I have a texture that is "shared" between the first and second framebuffer. See code:

```
func (o *OpenGL) Init() {
    o.opaqueFBO = newFramebuffer()
    o.transparentFBO = newFramebuffer()

    // OPAQUE FBO
    gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, o.opaqueFBO)
    opaqueFBOAttachments := []attachment{
        attachment{&o.opaqueTex0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0},
        attachment{&o.sharedDepthBuffer, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.FLOAT, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT},
    }
    o.attachFramebufferTextures(o.opaqueFBO, opaqueFBOAttachments)
    gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, 0)

    // TRANSPARENT FBO
    gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, o.transparentFBO)
    transparentFBOAttachments := []attachment{
        attachment{&o.transparentTex0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.FLOAT, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0},
        attachment{&o.transparentTex1, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1},
        attachment{&o.sharedDepthBuffer, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.FLOAT, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT},
    }
    o.attachFramebufferTextures(o.transparentFBO, transparentFBOAttachments)
    gl.BindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
}

// attachFramebufferTextures attaches textures to an existing framebuffer. Has a check to reuse one if it already has a value
func (o *OpenGL) attachFramebufferTextures(fib uint32, a []attachment) {
    for _, att := range a {
        if *att.textureID <= 0 {
            gl.GenTextures(1, att.textureID)
            gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, *att.textureID)
            gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT)
            gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT)
            gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST)
            gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST)
            gl.TexImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, att.internalFormat, int32(o.screenWidth), int32(o.screenHeight), 0, att.format, att.typ, nil)
        } else {
            log.Printf("> DEBUG: Texture %v seems to be shared with another framebuffers", *att.textureID)
            gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, *att.textureID)
        }

        gl.FramebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, att.point, gl.TEXTURE_2D, *att.textureID, 0)
        // gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0)
    }

    if gl.CheckFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE {
        log.Fatalf("Framebuffer Error Hex: 0x%x\nNow go look it up here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/go-gl/gl/master/v4.5-core/gl/package.go", gl.CheckFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER))
    }
}

// newFramebuffer generates and returns a new framebuffer
func newFramebuffer() uint32 {
    var fid uint32
    gl.GenFramebuffers(1, &fid)
    return fid
}

type attachment struct {
    textureID      *uint32
    internalFormat int32
    format         uint32
    typ            uint32
    point          uint32
}
```

So a few things that I've noted from testing is as follows:

-Changing the order of the "OPAQUE FBO" and "TRANSPARENT FBO" code blocks give different results. Why? They are both bound when I use then, and then unbound once I'm done.

-When I render out each framebuffer alone, the results are what I expect. However when I eventually render them to the default framebuffer as textures, I just get a black screen. The black I think might have to do with the following code

```
bindFramebuffer(o.transparentFBO)
gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
gl.DrawBuffers(2, &[]uint32{gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT1}[0])
gl.ClearBufferfv(gl.COLOR, 0, &[]float32{0, 0, 0, 1}[0])
gl.ClearBufferfv(gl.COLOR, 1, &[]float32{1, 1, 1, 1}[0])
```

#### Update

So the black screen had to do how I bind textures to the shaders. I had to first execute `gl.ActiveTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + n)` **BEFORE** running `gl.BindTexture(...)`. Very strangle but it is what it is.

The only problem I still have now is somehow "sharing" that depth buffer between the two FBOs. I'm not even sure anymore if it is what I'm supposed to do but the code I'm referencing seems to suggest it.

Comment: That won't solve the issue, but in case of `*att.textureID > 0`, the setting of the texture parameters (`gl.TexParameteri`) and the specification of the texture image (`gl.TexImage2D`) is superfluous, because it has been done already. (except the parameters would change). In your case you can generate the textures once, before you call `attachFramebufferTextures`

Comment: @Rabbid76 That is true, thank you. I've updated the code from my question to circumvent this.